# Clicking in TextFormField causes rebuild and text field subsequently loses focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My Flutter app has been working fine right up until yesterday at which point my login screen started acting strange. As soon as I click in either the username or password text fields the keyboard shows, immediately hides, and then everything rebuilds. I've seen several threads on similar issues online, but nothing that's helped me figure out what's going wrong here. This is the gist of the code:

```
  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: SingleChildScrollView(child: _buildBody()));
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return BlocProvider(create: (context) {
      _loginBloc = LoginBloc(auth);
      return _loginBloc;
    }, child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is LoginFailure) {
        _onWidgetDidBuild(() {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('${state.error}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        });
        _showErrorMessage(state.error);
      }
      return Container(
          height: Styles().height(),
          child: LoadingOverlay(
              color: Colors.black,
              opacity: 0.5,
              isLoading: (state is LoginLoading),
              progressIndicator: SpinKitThreeBounce(color: Colors.white),
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 50, 30, 0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          colors: [AppColors.DARK_BLUE, AppColors.GREEN])),
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50),
                        child: _showLogo()),
                    Card(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 5,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              child: ListView(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  _buildEmailInput(),
                                  _buildPasswordInput(),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                      child: ButtonTheme(
                                          height: 50,
                                          child: FlatButton(
                                            color: AppColors.MEDIUM_GREEN,
                                            child: Text(
                                                _formMode == FormMode.LOGIN
                                                    ? 'Sign in with Email'
                                                    : 'Create Account',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold)),
                                            onPressed: _validateAndSubmit,
                                          ))),
                                  _showSecondaryButton(),
                                  Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: _showLoginRecoveryModal,
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Forgot Password?',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE,
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ))),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ))),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            'OR',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                    ),
                    _buildGoogleButton()
                  ]))));
    }));
  }
  Widget _buildEmailInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        controller: _emailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Email',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              color: Colors.grey,
            )),
        validator: (value) => !EmailEditingRegexValidator().isValid(value)
            ? 'Invalid email address'
            : null,
        onSaved: (value) {
          if (StringUtils.isNotNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            _email = value.trim();
          } else {
            _email = null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPasswordInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        controller: _passwordController,
        obscureText: _hidePassword,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Password',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.lock,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            suffix: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _toggleShowPassword,
                child: Icon(
                  AntIcons.eye,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ))),
        validator: (value) => !NonEmptyStringValidator().isValid(value)
            ? 'Password can\'t be empty'
            : null,
        onSaved: (value) {
          if (StringUtils.isNotNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            _password = value.trim();
          } else {
            _password = null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm not sure what I need to do here to ensure that, as soon as the keyboard shows, everything does not get rebuilt.